# How do I use Silverlight + VB.NET to play audio?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Can any one tell me how to use Silverlight to play audio from local ASP.NET folders?

Comment: I think you're looking for http://www.rentacoder.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Audio and Video Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189078(VS.95).aspx)

[How to play audio or sound files from Silverlight](http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/Silverlight-Tutorial-326.aspx)

[Silverlight Tip of the Day #22 – How to add Sound Effects, Music and Video to your Silverlight App](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/25/tip-of-the-day-22-how-to-add-sound-effects-music-and-video-to-your-silverlight-app.aspx)

[Video and Audio (Silverlight QuickStart)](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/audioandvideo/)